# Internet Recovery Screen Stuck

Tags: imac, restart

I am attempting to factory reset my mid-2011 iMac, and so I tried to boot my iMac into Recovery Mode. I held `Cmd` + `R`, however it gave me a grey screen with a stop sign symbol, and then powered off. I tried several more times, and the same thing happened.

I then turned to the Internet, and found that there was something called Internet Recovery Mode, so I booted into that with `Cmd` + `alt` + `R`, which worked, and the little globe came up. After the loading bar finishing, the screen went white, and the Apple logo came up, and then it stayed that way for several hours until I powered it off, as it seemed to be stuck.

Is there a way to fix the recovery mode issue, as I just want to erase the hard disk?

Comment: Usually you download High Sierra and transfer to a flash drive. Boot From the flash drive, erase and reinstall.

Comment: Can I not just erase the hard drive from Disk Utility in Recovery Mode, and then reinstall OS X?